# EF Return Aggregated and Non-Aggregated Data

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, aggregate

Given the below table structure, how can I return the following aggregated **and** grouped fields using entity frawework.

**Required fields**
*Grouped:*
User.Forename
User.Surname

*Aggregated:*
Maximum(Order.OrderDate) 
Count(Order.OrderId)
Sum(Payment.Amount)
Count(Order.OrderId for all orders in last 60 days)
Sum(Payment.Amount for all orders in last 60 days)

**Tables**
*Users:*
UserId (PK)
Forename
Surname

*Orders:*
OrderId (PK)
UserId (FK)
OrderDate

*Payments:*
PaymentId (PK)
OrderId (FK)
PaymentAmount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime last60Days = new DateTime(xxx,xxx,xxx);

var query = from u in context.Users
            group u by new
            {
              u.Forename,
              u.Surname
            } into ug
            select new
            {
              Forename = ug.Key.Forename,
              Surname = ug.Key.Surname,
              MaxOrderdate = ug.SelectMany(x => x.Orders).Max(x => x.OrderDate),
              OrderCount = ug.SelectMany(x => x.Orders).Count(),
              Payment = ug.SelectMany(x => x.Orders.SelectMany(y => y.Payments)).Sum(x => x.PaymentAmount),
              OrderCountLast60 = ug.SelectMany(x => x.Orders).Where(x => x.OrderDate > last60Days).Count(),
              PaymentLast60 = ug.SelectMany(x => x.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderDate > last60Days).SelectMany(y => y.Payments)).Sum(x => x.PaymentAmount)
            };
```